# Installing ubuntu 12.10 - performance issues

Tags: installation, 12.10, nvidia

First question ever, well I'm trying to install ubuntu 12.10 in my laptop, however its laggy, slow, can't do anything, can barely install it.

Tryed with wubi, didn't work so well, went for a usb install, my partition table wasn't able to create a partition, now I'm doing it manually and will try to install again.
even tested with Kubunto to ditch unity, still slow, unbearable, taking 5 mins to open anything.

I dont know what the problem is, my laptop meets the requirements, i think.

```
specs:
geforce 240m     
4gb ram
intel core 2 duo t9600 2.8ghz
```

What do you guys think, really need to study a but in Ubuntu (bash and c pipes bah), is it the fail graphics card? anything that i should be doing?

thanks in advance
Roger
(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

First, a note - anything installed with Wubi is going to be slow, due to the way Wubi works.

That said, it might be worth running a diagnostic of your hard drive, if the install was also slow. Very often a major slowdown, especially in a clean OS install, is indicative of a hard drive going bad. I recommend Hitachi's Drive Fitness Test, Hiren's Boot CD, or the Ultimate Boot CD.

There's a difference between graphics-related slowness and slowness related to other issues. Generally, graphics slowness is lag in repainting actions, such as changing screens or scrolling through long documents. If you see this kind of slowness, too, make sure you've installed the Nvidia drivers. You can do this by first updating your computer (open Unity and search "update"), which also updates your video driver list. Once the updates are done, open the "Software sources" application and go to the "Additional Drivers" tab. Find the Nvidia driver that says either "stable" or "stable, tested" and select it.

On a final note, your specs are more than enough to run Ubuntu with Unity, Gnome-Shell, or KDE (also, KDE is on par with Unity as far as resource usage, so it's not surprising that going to Kubuntu didn't change anything), but if you want something lighter weight, then you might want to try LXDE (Lubuntu) or OpenBox. Also, the terminal isn't generally required in most cases for the general user anymore, but even when you do make use of it, it's not that bad (and who knows, maybe once you get used to it, you won't want to go back to some of the GUI interfaces ;) ).

Comment: the laggyness is in I/O operations i think, i will try to analyze my disk, maybe its that! thanks

Comment: :( downloaded and instaled HDFT you told me about, it cant even find my disk lol, defragging it atm, will update after

Comment: Defragging isn't going to do you much good for either DFT or Ubuntu (unless you're accessing files from your Windows partition). Defragging is a by-product of the file systems that Windows uses, and it just reorders the written bits on the Windows partition (kind of like organizing puzzle pieces).

Comment: You might want to try Hiren's Boot CD, which includes a variety of diagnostic tools. You can also have Ubuntu test it, if running as a Live CD works for you. These tools tend to be more sensitive than Windows at detecting hard drive issues, so it's possible your drive is farther gone than you think.